# Sorting in dojo datagrid

Tags: dojo

I am using  datagrid + jsonreststore (which is fetching data from a remote
server), now I am planning to support local sorting

I searched a lot and found we can enable local sorting ( no http rest sent 
)  by setting

queryOptions: {cache: true},

in the datagrid init

but seems it does not work always...

Answer (score 1):

I did the sorting this way:

```
dijit.byId("yourgrid").setSortIndex(1, false);
dijit.byId("yourgrid").sort();
```

where 1 is the column index to sort by, and false is for descending order. (true is ascending).